# appendChild element not available immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, disqus

I am using Vue.js to create a component for Disqus comments. The Disqus plugin simply requires an element with the id `disqus_thread` to function.  My Vue directive looks like this:

```
Vue.elementDirective('v-disqus',{
    params:['disqusUrl','disqusId','disqusTitle','disqusCategory'],
    bind(){
      var dc = document.createElement('div');
      dc.setAttribute('id','disqus_thread');
      this.el.appendChild(dc)
      setTimeout(() => {
        updateComments(this.params)
      },0)
    }
  });
```

The `updateComments()` function (edited for simplicity):

```
var updateComments = function(params){
  console.log('disqus thread:')
  console.log($('#disqus_thread')[0])
  ...
```

You'll see I have a `setTimeout` before calling `updateComments()`.  When I set that to 0, the console sometimes logs `undefined` for `$('#disqus_thread')[0]`.  When I set it to about 150, it is almost always long enough that the plugin loads fine.

So the question is, why would `this.el.appendChild` not fire immediately, and what do I have to do to ensure that element is there before calling `updateComments()`?

Edit: this is also inside of a `v-if`, however I would assume that this element directive would not compile until that becomes true.

Comment: `appendChild` is not asynchronous. Maybe `this.el` is not in the DOM yet.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I'm wondering if this is related to the transition effects that show and hide the content.  I've got it working currently by polling the DOM every 200 ms to look for the div before continuing, and that seems to work.

Comment: It could be, if the transition works by adding and removing elements instead of hiding and showing.